# Python: Get items that follow a specified element of a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings similar to `['ONE', 'TWO', 'SEVEN', 'TWELVE', 'ONE', 'SEVEN']`. Given a string that I know is in the list, is there a simple way to return an iterable of all of the elements that follow that string (and `None` if nothing follows it)?

So, inputing `'ONE'` would return `['TWO', 'SEVEN']` and inputing `'SEVEN'` would return `['TWELVE', None]`.

My current approach is to do something like:

```
follows = []
while test_string in string_list:
    index = string_list.index(test_string)
    if index + 1 < len(string_list):
        follows.append(string_list[index+1])
        string_list = string_list[index+1:]
    else:
        follows.append(None)
        string_list = []
```

But this seems overly cumbersome. If this is the best way, I can accept it. If there is a cleaner way, I'd love to learn it.

Comment: Special cases aren't special enough. The proper way to represent "no elements follow this", when the normal result is a list of the following elements, is **a list with no elements** (i.e. `[]`).

Comment: I looked over the other answers and realized that after spending considerable effort trying to understand what you were asking, I came to a completely different conclusion from everyone else about what you actually wanted. Please try to be more clear in the future. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
>>> a = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'SEVEN', 'TWELVE', 'ONE', 'SEVEN']
>>> [a[x+1] if x+1 < len(a) else None for x in range(len(a)) if a[x] == 'ONE']
['TWO', 'SEVEN']
```

Comment: Although you should update this to be an iterable and while you're at it you might as well use `xrange`.  =)

Comment: This is perfect. I always find it easier to go back and read python's list comprehensions than any sort of loop with conditionals. It kills me when I fail to see a way to write one and I think it should be possible. Thanks.

Comment: @dcurtis: I try to write answers that, where possible, work in both Python 2.x and Python 3.x. Python 3.x doesn't have `xrange()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'SEVEN', 'TWELVE', 'ONE', 'SEVEN']
k = 'ONE'
[l[i+1] if i<len(l)-1 else None for i,e in enumerate(l) if e==k]
```

Comment: This will fail for `k == "SEVEN"`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
from itertools import izip
[b for a, b in izip(string_list, string_list[1:] + [None]) if a == test_string]
```

Comment: While it doesn't fail for test_string == `'SEVEN'` it doesn't add `None` to the end.

Comment: @Wilduck: Maybe you had an old version of the page?  The old version did not add `None`, but there never was a version that failed for `test_string == "SEVEN"` (note that `izip()` terminates on the shortest sequence).

Comment: I did have an old version. I was refering to you mentioning that infrared's answer would fail for test_string == "SEVEN". In any case, you have my upvote. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Well... Feels like a generator could be a nice thing here.

```
>>> def follows(list, match):
...      i = iter(list)
...      x = next(i)
...      while x:
...          if x == match:
...              try:
...                  yield next(i)
...              except StopIteration:
...                  yield None
...          x = next(i)
... 
>>> [x for x in follows(['ONE', 'TWO', 'SEVEN', 'TWELVE', 'ONE', 'SEVEN'], 'SEVEN')]
['TWELVE', None]
>>> [x for x in follows(['ONE', 'TWO', 'SEVEN', 'TWELVE', 'ONE', 'SEVEN'], 'ONE')]
['TWO', 'SEVEN']
```

But cleaner? Matter of taste I guess.

Comment: This.  It's more readable than the list comprehensions above, and has the potential to outperform them, to boot.

Comment: This fails if the target appears twice consecutively in the list - for example, ['ONE','ONE','TWO','SEVEN','TWELVE','ONE','SEVEN'] should return ['ONE','TWO','SEVEN'] but instead returns ['ONE','SEVEN'].

Comment: @Hugh: Depends. That edge case is not defined in the spec. I claim my solution fulfills the specifications. :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>The process is:</s>

1. Find the first index of the element.
2. Get everything after that element.
3. Make a set out of those elements, since you apparently don't want duplicates.

This looks like:

```
set(the_list[the_list.index(the_element) + 1:])
```

Now that I've figured out what you're actually asking:

The process is:

1. Get pairs of adjacent elements, letting the last element be paired with `None`.
2. Return an iterable of the second element from each pair whose first element matches.

That looks like:

```
(x[1] for x in zip(the_list, the_list[1:] + [None]) if x[0] == the_element)
```